# How to install and use a new library for C in Code:blocks (Openssl)

Tags: c, hash, openssl, codeblocks

i beg for your help. It's been a week that i'm trying to download and use OpenSSl for a final project, but i find dificulties. My openssl is well downloaded: When I write openssl version on CMD it prints : OpenSSL 1.1.1i
The issue is when i try to include this library, it says than that there aren't any folder or file OpenSSl/sha.h
I have watched some tutorials on Ytb about how to use a new library, but it still don't work. I really need your help please. If you can tell me what to do from the beggining it'd be very nice.
If you are using another hash library you can always advise me and give me the steps.

I tried to add the folder include and lib on my codeblocks files, but it still doesn't work. I checked that the file Sha.h is added, but my codeblocks don't find it. I tried to use it on a virtual machine with ubuntu, and tried it on VS:Code, i have the same problem.

I've never used C before so it's the first time that i have to install a new library.

Comment: What package did you install and how? With Debian packages it is often the case that you have one package providing the library to be used by other application binaries. And another package providing all the headers you need if you want to build an application using the package, on your own.